# Routing Information Protocol implementation

Tags: algorithm, routes, distributed-computing

I am trying to implement a simulator for the Routing Information Protocol. I think I have most of the implementation done but I am not too sure about one part of the algorithm used when a node receives a table from a different node.

One of the if statements is as follows:

```
if address is known by p1 with a link of p2 then:
   if the cost for p2 is not exactly one less than p1's cost:
       act as if this address was unknown to p1
```

Where p1 is receiving a table from p2. Does this mean that if p1 has the address in its table and that the link associated with that address in p1 is a link to p2 then check whether the cost for p2 is not exactly less than p1s cost?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what it means.

When `p1` gets routing information about some network `n` from p2, it must decide whether or not to use the new route. Normally, it will use the new route (setting the link to `p2`) only if it is better than the route it currently knows for `n`. However, in the case that `p2` was the gateway it already had for `n` -- in other words, it got the information from `p2` earlier -- then it accepts the new information, even if the new cost is higher than the old cost.

This allows `p2` to inform its neighbours that it has lost connectivity to some other network (by setting its cost to the RIP equivalent of infinity). If the neighbours previously relied on `p2` to reach that network, they will now invalidate their routes to that network and await information from some other gateway which does have connectivity. It also allows `p2` to inform its neighbours that the cost of reaching `n` has increased and they should use a cheaper route if they can find one.